# Is Redis data volatile?

Tags: redis

I am trying to figure out something and I've been searching for a while with no results.

**What happens if a Redis server loses power or gets shut down or something that would wipe the RAM? Does it keep a backup somewhere?**

I am wanting to use Redis for a SaaS style app so if I go to app.com/usernamesapp it would use redis to verify usernamesapp exists and get the ID... At which point it would use MySQL for all the rest of the stuff... Reasons being I want to begin showing the page ASAP and most of the stuff is javascript so all the MySQL would happen after the fact.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redis can be configured to write to disk at regular intervals so if the server fails you wont lose your data.
http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 3):

From the Redis FAQ

> Redis is an in-memory but persistent on disk database

So a critical failure should not result in data loss. Read more at http://redis.io/topics/faq

Comment: So it does both simultaneously/it writes at to the disk at the moment where the data is stored? I was wondering if I can use it on my raspberry pi project but users might just pull the plug.

Comment: It's configurable. You can set an interval to save. Or you can log every command and have those replayed to rebuild your data set. The link in ArthurGuy's comment above is a good place to start: https://redis.io/topics/persistence